# Android NDK: ARMv6 + VFP devices. wrong calculations, NaN, denormal numbers, VFP11 bug

Tags: android-ndk, arm, nan, armv6

I wish to target ARMv6 with VFP Android device.

I have following line in my `Android.mk` file to enable `VFP`

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -marm -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -Wmultichar
```

I believe I target `ARMv5` with `VFP`.

I edited `android-ndk-r8b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\setup.mk` to remove `-msoft-float`. I also tried with original `setup.mk`

My code works fine 99.99% of time but some times goes crazy on ARMv6 devices.
I have special code to detect when it goes crazy.

**Code**

```
glm::vec3 D = P1 - P2;
float f1 = sqrtf(D.x*D.x + D.y*D.y + D.z*D.z);
if(!(f1 < 5)){
    // f1 is bigger then 5 or NaN
    mylog_fmt("Crazy %f %f %f %f", P1.x, P1.y, P1.z, f1);
    mylog_fmt("%f %f %f", P2.x, P2.y, P2.z);
}
```

**LogCat**:

```
12-14 00:59:08.214: I/APP(17091): Crazy -20.000031 0.000000 0.000000 20.000000
12-14 00:59:08.214: I/APP(17091): -20.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

It calculates distance between 2 points. Usually it is 0.000031
But when `crazy mode` is on it is 20.0

The problem does not exists when I run it on ARMv7 CPU. It exists on ARMv6 CPU only.

I believe it should be some common known bug related to compiler settings or version. May be codes is missing memory barrier.

I would like to see some reference to similar bugs. Way to solve it. Or about nature of bug.

I also often get NaN values on ARMv6 when same code on ARMv7 does not give NaN.

I am debugging code for for 2 weeks already and searching the web. If someone could share link to similar problem it would be a great help!

PS. here is example of one of compile commands. I tried many different settings already.

**Compiler Settings**

```
c:/soft/Android/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
-MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/main/sys/base.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector 
-D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__
-D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  
-march=armv5te -mtune=arm6 
-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp
-fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 
-Ijni/main/ -Ijni/main/sys -Ijni/main/bullet/src -Ijni/main/bullet/src/LinearMath -Ijni/main/bullet/src/BulletCollision/BroadphaseCollision 
-Ijni/main/bullet/src/BulletCollision/CollisionDispatch -Ijni/main/bullet/src/BulletCollision/CollisionShapes -Ijni/main/bullet/src/BulletCollision/NarrowPhaseCollision 
-Ijni/main/bullet/src/BulletDynamics/ConstraintSolver -Ijni/main/bullet/src/BulletDynamics/Dynamics -Ijni/main/../libzip/ -Ic:/soft/Android/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport 
-Ic:/soft/Android/android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl//gabi++/include -Ijni/main 
-DANDROID

-marm -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -Wmultichar

-Wa,--noexecstack  -frtti  -O2 -DNDEBUG -g   -Ic:/soft/Android/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include -c  jni/main/sys/base.cpp
-o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/main/sys/base.o
```

**UPDATE 2**

All these devices have Qualcomm MSM7227A 
It has ARM1136JF-S

What I learnt so far is that the bug could relate to `de-norms`
I read somewhere ARMv7 differences WITH ARMv6 that is has `denorms` flush to zero by default and ARM1136SF-S has it optionally.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0211k/DDI0211K_arm1136_r1p5_trm.pdf

Not yet sure how to verify that Flush-To-ZERO flag on ARM.

**UPDATE 3**

This CPU's VFP is called `VFP11`
I found `--vfp11-denorm-fix` option. 
There is also `--vfp-denorm-fix`
They correct erratum in `VFP11` cpus. Looks like my target problem.
Found few posts about VFP11 erratum. Hope it will fix the code.

Comment: NDK targets armeabi (ARMv5TE) by default. use `ndk-build V=1` to see how compiler is invoked. Don't mess with CFLAGS without purpose. Read $NDK/docs/APPLICATION-MK.html for eabis. There can be ARMv5 without VFP but those should crash not create strange results.

Comment: @auselen Thanks! ARMv5TE without VFP works fine. But math is 10 times slow and my app has physics simulation and uses OpenGL ES 2.0. I do not know OpenGL ES 2.0 ready phones without VFP. I am willing to enable VFP or at least read about similar cases or about the bug coursing the problem.

Comment: You should build for ARMv7 as well.

Comment: @auselen I do. Armv6 and armv7 code runs on armv7 devices. The problem is armv6 with Vfp on armv6 devices. Code works fine and 2-3 minutes after it starts making mistakes and then returns to normal state. Like CPU temperature changes. I added bug detectors. They are logging when calculations are wrong like in example.

Comment: "-mtune=arm6" sounds very wrong. arm6 is ARMv3 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microprocessor_cores). However I don't think it is your issue. Do you have an ARMv6 device that you can isolate this behavior on?

Comment: I had `-mtune=xscale` with same problem. I will try to target some newer CPU. If it is ARMv3 CPU then most likely setting was ignored. I was also removing mtune option.

Comment: Yes. I have that problem on Samsung Galaxy ACE, GIO, Y, Pocket, LGE GT540 and I think it is on all other ARMv6 devices when I run it on ARMv7 then it is OK. Tested on many ARMv7 devices, AVD emulator, simulators x86 and iOS ARMv7

Comment: Can you write a simple function to reproduce the problem?

Comment: No. Most of the time it works as it should. I have bug detectors in many places. I have bulletphysics and other math code. 99.99% it is Ok. After some time some bug detector print wrong values. Like CPU temperature changes CPU frequency and it changes command order execution.

Comment: And same android version? I wouldn't expect it to be a hw problem but may be library bug. You should dump hw state as much as possible like a core dump or tombstone to see what is different in *crazy* case compared to normal one.

Comment: More random things: is the craziness evident in the result of the multiply + add, or just in the result of `sqrtf`?  Do things change if you use `sqrt` (it's a different VFP instruction, assuming the compiler does what I think it will)?  Are all of the devices you tested based on a Qualcomm CPU?

Comment: If I split `sqrt(a*a + b*b + c*c)` to save variables step by step and log later then detector does not detect errors. I wished to see how it is calculated but could not. It even does not detect if I cacl everything together first and repeat it step by step. So it could be some optimization step. If I could tell GCC to not "optimize" then I solved the problem. May be it is Qualcomm only problem. Not sure. I could not run [AVD emulator in ARMv6 with VFP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915261/android-virtual-device-vfp-for-armv5) yet to reproduce it in emulator.

Comment: Could be dodgy compiler code gen + some external factor (e.g. context switch or signal arriving).  Could be something in VFP is getting into a weird state.  At some point, disassembly with the ARM version of `objdump` (or compilation with `-save-temps` to preserve the .S file) may be necessary to sort it out, and/or dumping the contents of the FP status register when you're in crazy-mode.

Comment: It should be 'MSM7227' not 'MSM7227A'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I identified bug.

It is bug in VFP11 (ARMv6 coprocessor) denorm bug.
[denormal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) are very small number.

I get this numbers in physics code implementing spring with dumping

```
force1 = (Center - P1) * k1         // force1 directed to center 
force2 = - Velocity * k2            // force2 directed against velocity
Object->applyForce(force1)
Object->applyForce(force2)
```

Both forces get very small when object archieve `Center` and I get `denormal` values at the end.

I can re-write sring and dumping but I can't re-write hole BulletPhysics or all math code and predict every (even internal) occurance of denormal number.

Linker has fix code options `--vfp11-denorm-fix` and `--vfp-denorm-fix` 
http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/ld/ARM.html

NDK linker has `--vfp11-denorm-fix`
This option helps. Code looks more repliable but it does not fix problem for 100%.

I see less bugs now.

BUt if I wait sping stabilize object then I finally I get denorm -> NaN

I have to wait longer but same problems arrive.

**If you know solution that will fix code like `--vfp11-denorm-fix` should then I give you bounty.**

I tried both `--vfp11-denorm-fix=scalar` and `--vfp11-denorm-fix=vector`

**Flush to Zero bit**

```
      int x;
      // compiles in ARM mode
      asm(
              "vmrs %[result],FPSCR \r\n"
              "orr %[result],%[result],#16777216 \r\n"
              "vmsr FPSCR,%[result]"
              :[result] "=r" (x) : :
      );
```

Not sure why but it requires `LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm` in `Android.mk`
May be `-mfpu=vfp-d16` instead of of just `vfp` is required.

**Manually clear denormal numbers**

I have spring code described above. 
I improved it by clearing denormal number manually without using FPU with following function.

```
inline void fixDenorm(float & f){
    union FloatInt32 {
        unsigned int u32;
        float f32;
    };
        FloatInt32 fi;
        fi.f32 = f;

        unsigned int exponent = (fi.u32 >> 23) & ((1 << 8) - 1);
        if(exponent == 0)
            f = 0.f;
}
```

---

Original code was failing in 15-90 seconds from start in many places.

Current code showed issue possibly related to this bug in only one in place after 10 minutes of physics simulation.

---

Reference to bug and fix
http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2006-12/msg00196.html

They say that `GCC` uses only scalr code and `--vfp11-denorm-fix=scalar` is enough.
It adds 1 extra command to slow down. But even `--vfp11-denorm-fix=vector` that adds 2  extra commands is not enough.

Problem is not easier re-producible. On phones with higher frequency 800Mhz I see it more often then on slower one 600Mhz. It is possible that fix was done when there was no fast CPUs on market.

---

We have many files in project and every configuration compilations takes around 10 minutes.
Testing with current state of fix requires ~10 minutes to play on phone. + We heat phone under the lamp. Hot phone shows errors faster.

I wish to test different configurations and report what fix is most efficient. But right now we have to add hack to kill last bug possibly related to denorms.

I expected to find silver bullet that will fix it but only `-msoft-float` with 10x performance degradation or running app on ARMv7 does it.

---

After I replaced previous `fixDenorm` function with new `fixDenormE` in spring/dumping code and applying the new function for ViewMatrix I get rid of last bug.

```
inline void fixDenormE(float & f, float epsilon = 1e-8){
    union Data32 {
        unsigned int u32;
        float f32;
    };
        Data32 d;
        d.f32 = f;

        unsigned int exponent = (d.u32 >> 23) & ((1 << 8) - 1);
        if(exponent == 0)
            f = 0.f;
        if(fabsf(f) < epsilon){
          f = 0.f;
        }
}
```

Comment: If this is your case, you should be able to reproduce it easily. Can you?

Comment: The sourceware.org link notes that this only affects full compliance mode, and does not affect "runfast" mode.  Can you confirm the state of the FPSCR register at the time of the weirdness?  (links: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344h/Chdiihcd.html http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BCFHFBGA.html http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BCFIDDIG.html ).

Comment: Yes. I added ASM code to set FlushToZero. It improves quality significantly but not so good as it works on ARMv7 or x86. With few more hacks I hope we can switch from software mode to hardware in production soon. Still there is no silver bullet for that problem.

Comment: Can you make a test with "-ffast-math"?

Comment: I am sorry I have not time to run all tests now. I still plan to do that later. But I had `-ffastmath` option in the beginning by default.   We submitted app's update yesterday and it works now. `fixDenormE` does the job. It keeps all numbers much above smallest float. We use `1e-8` vs `1e-37`. `1e-8` is still very small number if we talk about normalize matrix or angle.

Answer (score 0):

This page has an interesting discussion on ARM FPU options: [VfpComparison](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort/VfpComparison)

I think if you want to build for ARM v6, you might do this: `-march=armv6 -mcpu=generic-armv6 -mfloat-abi=softfp` (and leave out the -mfpu option).  If you are not targetting specifically the processor you mentioned above, generic armv6 doesn't have a guaranteed fpu.

Another option is to try `-mfloat-abi=hard`, on the theory that there is a compiler bug somewhere around softfp.

Also check for any stack corruption etc in your code, it is possible that when floating point values are passed you clobber them.

P.S. You might also want to try out a floating-point tester such as [TestFloat](http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/TestFloat.html) or the venerable netlib [paranoia](http://www.netlib.org/paranoia/paranoia.c).  While you have an example of floating point failing on this particular processor and with these compiler options, you don't know how widespread a problem it is.  It could be worse than you think :)

Comment: `-mfloat-abi=hard` is not good idea. Android it self is compiled with `-mfloat-abi=softfp` I could use `hard` if I recompiled Android as well not only my app. I will look your links. I am almost sure I already found the bug I mentioned in UPDATE 3. It would be great to confirm bug with test suite.

Comment: [VfpComparison](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort/VfpComparison)  tells that they will not support ARMv6 and VFPv2. VFPv2 is our VFP11 that has bug.