# Android Virtual Device VFP for ARMv5

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, armv6

AVD has VFP support for armeabi-v7a but has not for armeabi.

I experience [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870691/android-ndk-armv6-vfp-devices-wrong-calculations-nan) with float point on ARMv6 and wish to setup ARMv6 with FPU on virtual device.
(It is hardware similar to Samsung Galaxy ACE, Y, Pocket, GIO)

So I look for solution to get another CPU/ABI option for Android Virtual Device.

UPDATE

AVD settings are located in
~/.android/avd/config.ini

It is possible to add line like

hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8

Right now it does not work
If you know required settings I will mark your answer as response. +1

Comment: AVD is a shell around QEMU. Search for QEMU support on those.

Comment: I know I even have found option hw.cpu.model. But I can't find docs where hw.cpu.model.